# Why isn't Google's Gson static?

Tags: java, static, gson, instance

Out of curiosity, why do I have to instantiate `Gson`? I can't see any reason as to why `Gson#toJson` and `Gson#fromJson` can't be static. Doing `new Gson().toJson(...)` every time seems silly when I could simply use `Gson.toJson(...)`. Is there some instance specific data being generated I am not aware of?

Comment: Too bad Gson's source code can't be viewed before asking the question. But, well, you can at least read it now: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/Gson.java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because a `Gson` object may be made by using [GsonBuilder](http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html) which allows `Gson` to have configuration options other than the default ones.